# selecting correct list of Enums from 2 derived classes

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, modeling

I'm building a book library app, I have a abstract book Class, two types of derived books and two Enums that will save the genre of the book.
Each Book can be related to one genre or more.

```
    abstract public class Book
    {   
       public int Price { get; set; } 
       ...
    }

    public enum ReadingBooksGenre
    {
       Fiction,
       NonFiction
    }

    public enum TextBooksGenre
    {
        Math,
        Science
    } 

    abstract public class ReadingBook : Book
    { 
        public List<ReadingBooksGenre> Genres { get; set; }
    }

    abstract public class TextBook : Book
    {   
        public List<TextBooksGenre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i want to save the discounts based on the book genres (no double discounts, only the highest discount is calculated), so i'm thinking about making two dictionaries that will save all the discounts for each genre, like this:

```
    Dictionary<ReadingBooksGenre, int> _readingBooksDiscounts;
    Dictionary<TextBooksGenre, int> _textBooksDiscounts;
```

So now i need to check the genre of each book in order to find the highest discount, is there any better way to do it than:

```
    private int GetDiscount(Book b)
    {
        int maxDiscount = 0;
        if (b is ReadingBook)
        {
            foreach (var genre in (b as ReadingBook).Genres)
            {
                // checking if the genre is in discount, and if its bigger than other discounts.
                if (_readingBooksDiscounts.ContainsKey(genre) && _readingBooksDiscounts[genere]>maxDiscount)
                {
                    maxDiscount = _readingBooksDiscounts[genere];
                }
            }
        }
        else if (b is TextBook)
        {
            foreach (var genre in (b as TextBook).Genres)
            {
                if (_textBooksDiscounts.ContainsKey(genre) && _textBooksDiscounts[genere]>maxDiscount)
                {
                    maxDiscount = _textBooksDiscounts[genere];
                }
            }
        }
        return maxDiscount;
    }
```

is there a way to select the correct dictionary without checking for the type? 
or maybe even a way to do it without the dictionaries, or using one?
maybe somehow connect book type with the Enum?

will be glad to hear any suggestions for improvement.

(there are a lot of more discounts based on books name, date and author. Even some more book types that is why this way doesn't seem right to me)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit leery of a model where textbooks _aren't_ a subset of non-fiction. Although I suppose one must make allowances for J. K. Rowling's _Quidditch Through The Ages_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetDiscount` method is classic example of [Open/Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) violation.  When you add new book type you have to add new `if` block to `GetDiscount`.

Better way is to use some existing techinques which allow you to add new functionality without necessity to modify existing code.  For example, [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  I'll write some draft implementation of composite discount evaluator.  You can add new discount evaluators based on any book proerties (date, price, etc.) easily.

Also, I'll use interfaces instead of inheritance.  Inheritance is a very strong link between two entities and in this case it is excessive.

Listing is 167 lines long, so here is more comfort [pastebin copy](http://pastebin.com/SyM0cK6u)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var compositeDiscountEvaluator = ConfigureEvaluator();
            var scienceBook = new TextBook
                               {
                                   Date = DateTime.Now,
                                   Price = 100,
                                   Genres = new[] {TextBooksGenre.Math}
                               };
            var textBook = new TextBook
                               {
                                   Date = DateTime.Now,
                                   Price = 100,
                                   Genres = new[] {TextBooksGenre.Math, TextBooksGenre.Science}
                               };
            var fictionBook = new ReadingBook
                        {
                            Date = DateTime.Now,
                            Price = 200,
                            Genres = new[] {ReadingBooksGenre.Fiction}
                        };
            var readingBook = new ReadingBook
                                  {
                                      Date = DateTime.Now,
                                      Price = 300,
                                      Genres = new[] {ReadingBooksGenre.Fiction, ReadingBooksGenre.NonFiction}
                                  };
            Console.WriteLine(compositeDiscountEvaluator.GetDiscount(scienceBook));
            Console.WriteLine(compositeDiscountEvaluator.GetDiscount(textBook));
            Console.WriteLine(compositeDiscountEvaluator.GetDiscount(fictionBook));
            Console.WriteLine(compositeDiscountEvaluator.GetDiscount(readingBook));
        }

        private static IDiscountEvaluator ConfigureEvaluator()
        {
            var evaluator = new CompositeDiscountEvaluator();
            evaluator.AddEvaluator(new ReadingBookDiscountEvaluator());
            evaluator.AddEvaluator(new TextBookDiscountEvaluator());
            return evaluator;
        }
    }

    class CompositeDiscountEvaluator : IDiscountEvaluator
    {
        private readonly ICollection<IDiscountEvaluator> evaluators;

        public CompositeDiscountEvaluator()
        {
            evaluators = new List<IDiscountEvaluator>();
        }

        public void AddEvaluator(IDiscountEvaluator evaluator)
        {
            evaluators.Add(evaluator);
        }

        public bool CanEvaluate<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book)
        {
            return evaluators.Any(e => e.CanEvaluate(book));
        }

        public int GetDiscount<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book)
        {
            if (!CanEvaluate(book))
                throw new ArgumentException("No suitable evaluator");
            return evaluators.Where(e => e.CanEvaluate(book)).Select(e => e.GetDiscount(book)).Max();
        }
    }

    interface IDiscountEvaluator
    {
        bool CanEvaluate<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book);
        int GetDiscount<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book);
    }

    class ReadingBookDiscountEvaluator : IDiscountEvaluator
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<ReadingBooksGenre, int> discounts;

        public ReadingBookDiscountEvaluator()
        {
            discounts = new Dictionary<ReadingBooksGenre, int>
                            {
                                {ReadingBooksGenre.Fiction, 3},
                                {ReadingBooksGenre.NonFiction, 4}
                            };
        }

        public bool CanEvaluate<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book)
        {
            return book is ReadingBook;
        }

        public int GetDiscount<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book)
        {
            var readingBook = (ReadingBook) book;
            return readingBook.Genres.Select(g => discounts[g]).Max();
        }
    }

    class TextBookDiscountEvaluator : IDiscountEvaluator
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<TextBooksGenre, int> discounts;

        public TextBookDiscountEvaluator()
        {
            discounts = new Dictionary<TextBooksGenre, int>
                            {
                                {TextBooksGenre.Math, 1},
                                {TextBooksGenre.Science, 2}
                            };
        }

        public bool CanEvaluate<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book)
        {
            return book is TextBook;
        }

        public int GetDiscount<TGenre>(IBook<TGenre> book)
        {
            var textBook = (TextBook) book;
            return textBook.Genres.Select(g => discounts[g]).Max();
        }
    }

    interface IBook<TGenre>
    {
        int Price { get; set; }
        DateTime Date { get; set; }
        TGenre[] Genres { get; set; }
    }

    class ReadingBook : IBook<ReadingBooksGenre>
    {
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public ReadingBooksGenre[] Genres { get; set; }
    }

    class TextBook : IBook<TextBooksGenre>
    {
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public TextBooksGenre[] Genres { get; set; }
    }

    enum TextBooksGenre
    {
        Math,
        Science
    }

    public enum ReadingBooksGenre
    {
        Fiction,
        NonFiction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a generic method which accepts the dictionaries and the book of corresponding type. This way you can get the algorithm generic enough and your code quite clean. Naturally this way the GetDiscount would be also generic, but you could not mix them in a wrong way. (Oh, yes, Book would be also generic with the Genres returning the proper type.)
I think this code can be implemented with a bit of LINQ, but maybe it does not worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the concept of "genre" in your system is too complicated for a simple enum. I'd promote the concept to its own class hierarchy:

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Discount { get; set; }
}
public class ReadingBooksGenre : Genre { }
public class TextBooksGenre : Genre { }

abstract public class Book<T> where T : Genre
{
    public List<T> Genres { get; set; }
    public int Discount
    {
        get
        {
            return (Genres.Count == 0) ? 0 : Genres.Max(g => g.Discount);
        }
    }
}
abstract public class ReadingBook : Book<ReadingBooksGenre> { }
abstract public class TextBook : Book<TextBooksGenre> { }
```